# Query MySQL con If

Tags: mysql

espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, estoy trabajando en un Query y necesito saber como hacer lo siguiente...

Tengo una aplicacion que se usa para el inventario anual.

Tengo que hacer un reporte donde selecciono toda la informacion de la tabla donde se almacena la contabilidad de las piezas, en donde lo identifico si se conto 1, 2 o 3 veces el mismo numero de parte esto para confirmar si la primera vez que se conto es la correcta o no, pero el mismo numero de parte puede estar en 1 o mas puntos de estacion de la planta...

algo como lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora, el query que necesito es el siguiente. si se conto 2 veces el numero de parte en la misma ubicacion se tome la cantidad del segundo conteo o si se conto 3 veces, tome el valor del conteo y si se conto solo una vez, me iteresa que se tome el ultimo valor del numConteo, pues tomar el valor de cantidad de ese conteo, y posterior unir el numero de parte sumando la cantidad (Espero haberme explicado)

> Actualizacion

```
Parte    cantidad
2304241  161
```

Teniendo en cuanta que el total en este caso fue la suma del numConteo 2 de prensa Verson, numConteo 1 de lec 040F, numConteo 1 de led 030F, y numConteo 3 de lea kit 050f

Comment: Pone por favor un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y un ejemplo de la salida esperada....

Comment: @gbianchi listo

Answer (score 0):

Tiene varias opciones disponibles para obtener lo esperado. Una opción es un `LEFT JOIN` sobre la misma tabla:

```sql
SELECT
  `contabilidadpiezasmenor`.`parte`,
  SUM(`contabilidadpiezasmenor`.`cantidad`) `cantidad`
FROM
  `contabilidadpiezas` `contabilidadpiezasmenor`
  LEFT JOIN `contabilidadpiezas` `contabilidadpiezasmayor` ON
    `contabilidadpiezasmenor`.`ubiclinea` = `contabilidadpiezasmayor`.`ubiclinea` AND
    `contabilidadpiezasmenor`.`numconteo` < `contabilidadpiezasmayor`.`numconteo`
WHERE
  `contabilidadpiezasmayor`.`numconteo` IS NULL
GROUP BY
  `contabilidadpiezasmenor`.`parte`
ORDER BY
  `contabilidadpiezasmenor`.`parte`;
```

Otra opción, en versiones recientes de MySQL puede ser usar la cláusula `WITH`:

```sql
WITH `contabilidadpiezasmaximo` AS (
  SELECT
    `parte`,
    `cantidad`,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY `parte`, `ubiclinea`
      ORDER BY `numconteo` DESC
    ) `maximo`
  FROM
    `contabilidadpiezas`
)
SELECT
  `parte`,
  SUM(`cantidad`) `cantidad`
FROM
  `contabilidadpiezasmaximo`
WHERE
  `maximo` = 1
GROUP BY
  `parte`
ORDER BY
  `parte`;
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a004bdd365a193b09949f21dadaa9b4).